# Update Sub-Document properties using a Variable In Key Name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I know how to update objects within an array like the following:

```
db.bar.update( {user_id : 123456 , "items.item_name" : "my_item_two" } , 
                {$inc : {"items.$.price" : 1} } , 
                false , 
                true);
```

But, im trying to currently update a object.

model:

```
  boats: {
        cash: {type: Number, default: 0},
        amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
    murder: {
        attempts: {type: Number, default:0},
        failed_attempts: {type: Number, default:0},
        successfull_attempts: {type: Number, default:0},
        cash: {type: Number, default: 0},
        amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
    orgcrime: {
        cash: {type: Number, default: 0},
        amount: { type: Number, default: 0}
    },
```

i have a variable called `type` that contains the word i want to update, for example: murder . I also have a variable called `num`, that will be updated value.

`CurrentStats` contains the full model result.

i get the type`s object by doing:`currentStats[type]` , but how can i update it?

i tried with:

```
var x = {};
        x[type].cash = num;
        x[type].amount = 1;
```

and `{$inc: x}` , but that wouldnt work.

How would i go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean to actually form the field names using ["Dot Notation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation), by concatenating the name of the key:

```
var type = "murder";

var x = { };

x[type + ".cash"] = 1;
x[type + ".amount"] = 2;

db.bar.update({},{ "$inc": x });
```

Modern ES6 Notation also allows other forms like :

```
db.bar.update(
  {},
  { 
    "$inc": {
      [type + ".cash"]: 1,
      [`${type}.amount`]: 2
    }
  }
);
```

Either way forms

```
{
  "$inc": {
    "murder.cash": 1,
    "murder.amount": 2
  }
}
```

Which is what you want to update those properties and **only** those properties when making changes to the document.